# Is it possible to update unavailable days without destroy jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have jQuery Datepicker with unavailable dates:

```
var disabledDates = ["23.05.2017", "24.05.2017"];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

The only way i found to update disabledDates was to destroy datepicker, update unavailable dates and re-init.

```
// Destroy
$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");

// Update unavailable times
disabledDates = ["23.05.2017", "24.05.2017", "25.05.2017", "26.05.2017"];

// Re-init
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

Is there a other/better way to do it?

Comment: did you try to use the following syntax? `$("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "beforeShowDay", yourNewFunction )`

Comment: Use [`$('#datepicker').datepicker('refresh');`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh).

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes that do the job. Thanks.

Comment: @quirimmo that also work.

Comment: cool, two solutions at the same minute :D
@Phylogenesis I think that for the current issue yours is the best one, so go on with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destroy it, simply change the `beforeShowDay` property, see following please:

```js
var disableddates = ["20-05-2017", "21-05-2017"];

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
  var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
  return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}
  
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });  
});

$("#btn1").click(function(){
      disableddates = ["01-05-2017", "02-05-2017"];
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
      });
      console.log("Disabled dates changed");
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Change dates">
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: you should change it to:
`$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", DisableSpecificDates);`, that's the right way to update whatever option to the datepicker object